# Show that $A\triangle B \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle B_i$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Exercise:** Let $I$ be the index set and let $A_i,B_i\in\mathcal{B}((a,b])$ for all $i\in I$. Let $A = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ and $B = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i$

Show that $A\triangle B \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle B_i$, where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference.

*What I've tried:* I know that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle B_i = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\backslash B_i \cup B_i\backslash A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i \backslash B_i\cup \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i\backslash A_i$. Hence, I would say that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i \backslash B_i\cup \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i\backslash A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}B_i = A \triangle B_i.$ However this doesn't feel right as I need to show that $A\triangle B \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle B_i$ and not $A\triangle B = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i\triangle B_i$.

**Question:** How do I solve this exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x\in A\mathbin{\triangle}B$.

Consider the case $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ (the case $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$ is identical).

By definition, $x\in A_{i_0}$ for some $i_0$. Since $x\notin B$, we infer that $x\notin B_{i_0}$. Therefore $x\in A_{i_0}\mathbin{\triangle}B_{i_0}$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

$$A\setminus B=\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)\setminus \left(\bigcup_{j\in I} B_j\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(A_i\setminus \bigcup_{j\in I} B_{j}\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(\bigcap_{j\in I}(A_i\setminus B_j)\right)$$ Now, since the index sets are the same, for any fixed $i\in I$, $\bigcap\limits_{j\in I} A_i\setminus B_j\subseteq A_i\setminus B_i$. Therefore, $A\setminus B\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i\setminus B_i\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i\triangle B_i$. For the same reason, $B\setminus A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} B_i\triangle A_i$.
Hence, $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i\triangle B_i$.